# Why it is program showing the IllegalArgumentException I threw despite having the correct format for FillInQuestion? I put all class files for context

Tags: java, oop

```
public class FillInQuestion extends Question {
    
    public FillInQuestion(String sentence, DifficultyLevel diff) {
          super(parseQ(sentence), parseA(sentence), diff);
          
    }
    /**
     * Takes a sentence string and replace the answer surrounded by a specific patterb with a blank 
     * 
     * @param sentence
     * @return finalquestion the question with a blank
     * @throws IllegalAArgumentException if format is not met
     */
    **private static String parseQ(String sentence){    
        int startindex = sentence.indexOf("_-");
        int endindex = sentence.indexOf("-_");
        if (startindex == -1 || endindex == -1 || endindex <= (startindex + 2)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fill in Question does not contain the correct format");
        }
        String answer = sentence.substring(startindex+2, endindex);
        String finalquestion = sentence.replace("_-" + answer + "-_", "_________");
        return finalquestion;**
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param sentence
     * @return selected answer from a string
     */
    private static String parseA(String sentence) {
        int startindex = sentence.indexOf("_-");
        int endindex = sentence.indexOf("-_");
        return sentence.substring(startindex+2, endindex);
    }

    /**Creates a copy of FillinQuestion
     * 
     * @return a copy of FillinQuestion
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public Question copy(){
        return new FillInQuestion(this.getQuestion(), this.getDifficulty());
    }
}
```

```
public class QuizManager {
    /**
     * Asks users for questions, take in user input and then have a score system
     * 
     * @param questions ArrayList of Questions
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void giveQuiz(ArrayList<Question> questions) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        if (questions.isEmpty()) { //Throws exception in the case of empty arraylist
          throw new Exception("Questions Not Found Empty Quiz");
        }
        for (Question q : questions) {
          System.out.println(q.displayQuestion());
          System.out.print("Your answer: ");
          String userAnswer = s.nextLine();
          if (q.checkAnswer(userAnswer)) {
            score++;
          }
        }
        System.out.println("You scored " + score + " out of " + questions.size() + ".");
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        QuizMaker quizMaker = new QuizMaker("General Pop Quiz"); // New Object
        //Questions
        quizMaker.add(new Question("When did World War I started?", "1914", Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("How many fundamental states of matter are there? (State the number only)", "4", Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("Which three numbers have the same answer whether they are added or multiplied together?", "1, 2 and 3", Question.DifficultyLevel.MEDIUM));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("How many wonders of the world are there (Numbers Only)", "7", Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("What is the capital city of Australia", "Canberra", Question.DifficultyLevel.MEDIUM));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("What is the largest capital city in North America?", "Mexico City", Question.DifficultyLevel.HARD));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("Who was the first person to create the first gasoline-powered car?", "Karl Benz", Question.DifficultyLevel.HARD));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("State a palindrome number between 10 and 20", "11", Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("\n\nString str1 = \"InterviewBit\";\n"
                + "String str2 = \"InterviewBit\";\n"
                + " \n"
                + "System.out.println(str1 == str2);\n\nWhat will the code print?", "True", Question.DifficultyLevel.HARD));
        quizMaker.add(new Question("I’m tall when I’m young, and I’m short when I’m old. What am I?", "Candle", Question.DifficultyLevel.MEDIUM));
        **quizMaker.add(new FillInQuestion("The color _-white-_ is the most common color found on flags.", Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));**
        //quizMaker.add(new NumericQuestion("VALUE OF PI?", 3.14, 0.01, Question.DifficultyLevel.EASY));
        
        ArrayList<Question> allQuestions = quizMaker.createQuiz();
        ArrayList<Question> hardQuestions = quizMaker.createQuiz(Question.DifficultyLevel.HARD);

        //Exception Handling
        try {
              System.out.println("Full Quiz for : ");
              giveQuiz(allQuestions);
              System.out.println("\nHard Quiz: ");
              giveQuiz(hardQuestions);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
      }     
}
```

```
public class QuizMaker {
    private String name;
      private ArrayList<Question> pool;
      
      /**
       * Constructor with name as an instance 
       * 
       * @param name the name of the QuizMaker instance
       */
      public QuizMaker(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pool = new ArrayList<>();
      }
      /*
       * Question is copied into the pool
       * 
       * @param q Question q that will be added to the pool
       */
      public void add(Question q) {
        this.pool.add(q.copy());
      }

      
      /*
       * @return the name of the QuizMaker Instance
       */
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      /**
       * Sets the name of the QuizMaker instance.
       * 
       * @param name the new name of the QuizMaker instance
       */
      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      /**
       * Creates quiz from the question pool
       * 
       * @return an ArrayList of Question objects representing the quiz
       */
      public ArrayList<Question> createQuiz() {
        ArrayList<Question> quiz = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Question q : pool) {
          quiz.add(q.copy());
        }
        return quiz;
      }
      
      /**
       * Creates a specific difficulty quiz from pool of questions
       * 
       * @param difficulty the difficulty level of the questions 
       * @return an ArrayList of Question with the specific difficulty
       */
      public ArrayList<Question> createQuiz(Question.DifficultyLevel difficulty) {
        ArrayList<Question> quiz = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Question q : pool) {
          if (q.getDifficulty() == difficulty) {
            quiz.add(q.copy());
          }
        }
        return quiz;
      }

}
```

```
public class Question {
    /*
     * Enum class representing the difficulty of the question 
     */
    public enum DifficultyLevel {
        EASY, MEDIUM , HARD;
    }
    
    //Instance values 
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private DifficultyLevel difficulty;
    
    
    /**
     * Constructs a question with the given question text, answer, and difficulty level.
     * 
     * @param question the question string
     * @param answer the answer string
     * @param difficulty the difficulty level of the question
     */
     public Question(String question, String answer, DifficultyLevel difficulty) {
            this.question = question;
            this.answer = answer;
            this.difficulty = difficulty;
          }
     
     /**
         * Constructs a new question with the given question and answer, and  default difficulty level of `EASY`.
         * 
         * @param question the question string
         * @param answer the answer string
         */
     public Question(String question, String answer) {
            this.question = question;
            this.answer = answer;
            this.difficulty = DifficultyLevel.EASY;
          }


 /**
    * 
    * 
    * @return question string
    */
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    
    /**
     * Set Given Question
     * @param question
     */
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return answer string
     */
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    /**Set the answer
     * 
     * @param answer from given answer
     */
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return difficulty ENUM difficulty level
     */
    public DifficultyLevel getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    /**
     * Set difficulty level
     * @param difficulty 
     */
    public void setDifficulty(DifficultyLevel difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param userInput the user's answer 
     * @return a boolean whether the answer is true or not
     */
    public boolean checkAnswer(String userInput) {
        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(getAnswer())) {
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
    
    /**Displays the question and the difficulty level of the question 
     * 
     * @return whole question and its difficulty
     */
    public String displayQuestion() {
        return "Question: " + this.getQuestion() + "\nDifficulty: " + this.getDifficulty();
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the string summary
     */
    public String toString() {
            return "Question: " + question + ", Answer: " + answer + ", Difficulty Level: " + difficulty;
    }
    
    /**Creates a new question with the same question, answer and difficulty
     * 
     * @return a copy of the question 
     */
    public Question copy() {
        return new Question(this.getQuestion(), this.getAnswer(), this.getDifficulty());
      }

}
```

I expected to the code I bolded to run smoothly without throwing the exception I implemented. It shouldn't happen since the format is correct. I don't know what I did wrong but basically o    `parseQ(“The sky is _-blue-_”)` should return “The sky is _________” but I tried with the method but it only throws the exception. Also I am not allowed to use regex patterns.

Comment: By the way, bold and italics don't work in formatted code.

Comment: This would be a good program to step through using a debugger.

Comment: Class `QuizManager` does not compile since it refers to class `NumericQuestion`. I assume that is also a class that you wrote. In any case, in order for your code to compile on my computer, I need class `NumericQuestion`.

Comment: I would add the `sentence` to the error message of the exception so you can check what is wrong.... e.g. `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fill in Question does not contain the correct format: " + sentence);` (as a developer it is always *nice* to have some more information if something didn't work [specially user input]) || BTW if I test posted method with `parseQ("The sky is _-blue-_")` , I get `"The sky is _________"` - much probably that is not the argument that is causing problems

Comment: ( I could reproduce the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fill in Question does not contain the correct format: The color _________ is the most common color found on flags.`  - apparently this method is being called twice for the same text... `FillInQuestion.copy()` is found on the stack trace - this should indicate the problem )

Comment: I commented out the code for the NumericQuestion class in case it won't compile on your consoles. NumericQuestion works just fine but FillInquestion is not

Comment: So, did the *"I could reporduce the error"* comment from @user16320675 lead to resolving the problem?

Comment: I figured out that the method for parseQ was correct so it had to something with the copy method, and someone commented the method was running two times so I solved it. Thank you for the suggestions.